# Поиск по переменным вложенных классов

Tags: c#, классы, поиск

У меня есть основной класс содержащий множество классов. Для примера возьмем несколько:

```
 public class Data
{
    public Monkeyking MonkeyKing { get; set; }
    public Jax Jax { get; set; }
    public Shaco Shaco { get; set; }
    public Warwick Warwick { get; set; }
    public Xayah Xayah { get; set; }
    public Nidalee Nidalee { get; set; }
    public Zyra Zyra { get; set; }
}
```

И вот например несколько вложенных классов

```
 public class Monkeyking
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Jax
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Shaco
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Можно ли как то реализовать поиск среди  всех вложенных классов что бы сравнивать введенное значение с `id` во вложенных классах и вывести весь класс в котором `id`совпадет с введенными данными

Comment: Выкинуть все эти классы, так как они по сути одинаковы. Ну или наследовать их от общего класса-предка или интерфейса.

Answer (score 1):

У вас неверная структура данных.

Скорее всего, вам нужен не класс, а словарь персонажей:

```
public class Character
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ну и

```
string[] names = { "Monkeyking", "Jax", "Shaco", "Warwick", "Xayah", "Nidalee", "Zyra" };
Dictionary<string, Character> Data = names.ToDictionary(n => n, n => new Character());
```

При этом поиск можно проводить через LINQ:

```
var keys = Data.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Id == 1).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

(В случае, если нужно искать много и часто, стоит проиндексировать по `id`.)